# how to concatenate term name with it's parent name in select list

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I have created cck field as select list and selected the taxonomy terms and displaying all taxonomy terms in the select list. Then How can I add its parent name besides it.

let say India->Mumbai->Pune need to disaply as below in select list:

India (No Parent)
Mumbai (India)
Pune (mumbai)

IN Drupal 7?

Comment: Which version are you using D7 or D6 ?

Comment: On a side note: Mumbai is in India, however Pune is not inside Mumbai(they are separate cities); talking geographically.